# Random smiley face printing when I use pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For whatever reason whenever I use pd.read_csv there is a random smiley face ':)' printed to the shell. I have absolutely no clue why. Any ideas how to fix this?

I have tried digging through the source code for pandas on my computer to see if there is any mention of any such print statements but I've come up empty.
I can run only a read_csv call and it still happens.

This is the entirety of the code that replicates the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('whysmiley.csv')
```

And the shell's output:

```
:)
```

There are no print statements anywhere in my code so there's no reason to print anything out. Here's a test csv file to show off the problem:

```
,col1,col2,col3
0,0.3165,0.8295,0.9098
1,0.6410,0.8517,0.9206
2,0.8716,0.8375,0.8292
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: that most likely means your file is just a single line with `:)` on it.

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: What is producing `RESTART:`?

Comment: @QuangHoang It isn't - the entire contents of the file are in my description.

Comment: @roganjosh See the first code snippet in the description. That's the entirety of the code. The second snippet is the shell output

Comment: @KCarow I assume they meant: What are the contents of whysmiley.csv? Could there be a smiley face in that csv file?

Comment: @Dmiters Ah yeah, I just understood that -- I just made a tiny file that would load normally. Here's an image of the file: http://imgur.com/wGWqwaC

Comment: I'm guessing the same thing that is causing the `RESTART: <yourpathhere>` is printing the smiley. That is an unusual print for a read_csv afaik.

Comment: What pandas version do you use?   (pd.__version__)

Comment: @IWHKYB that RESTART stuff is just IDLE restarting the program. I'll delete it from the post to avoid confusion

Comment: Does this happen with all files read via pandas or just the one provided?

Comment: What happens if you load the file in using `open('whysmiley.csv').read()`?

Comment: Your csv file appears to be missing the first column's name? Pandas would substitute a `Unnamed: 0` text for that column header. Of course, I don't quite think that's connected to what you're seeing, but thought I'd point out the inconsistency in the CSV file.

Comment: @mlotz version 0.24.2

Comment: @ASGM Nothing is printed out when I use open instead. So I'm thinking there must be something wacky with pandas.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston All the ones I've tried do the same.

Comment: Perhaps try re-installing Pandas?  Just a fancier version of "turning it off and on again," but it might work.

Comment: @ASGM As much as I would think that would fix the problem, it still persists :/

Comment: Try the example given [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#column-and-index-locations-and-names) where the input is a StringIO. If this works, the issue may be with the file system in some way (permissions, etc.); if not, it's definitely a pandas problem.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston Well, it still prints a smiley. I suppose I'll have to dig around in the source code for pandas and find the reason. Any ideas of an efficient way to do that?

Comment: Very strange. Well, read_csv is [defined here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ee6b1318ff07806ead79dac8119ad9ce580afe1c/pandas/io/parsers.py#L724), but I couldn't find any reference to `:)` in the repo either. It may be deeper than just pandas - they may use another package, like `io`, to do some file parsing, and that package is the one that throws the smiley.

Comment: I would suggest creating a virtual environment using `conda` and trying again from there. A band-aid fix, yes, but a good-practice one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've fixed it. Doing a clean uninstall/reinstall of python resolved my problem (also I think I had the 32bit version on my 64bit machine, but I really don't see why that would cause a smiley face on one command of one module...).

Overall very strange. Thanks for all the ideas everyone.

Recap:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling pandas did not resolve the problem.
- All methods suggested to me didn't either (thanks anyway)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling python (changing from 32 to 64 bit installation) resolved it.